# How to make a trained Torch model Transformeres-compatible?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I have trained and saved a PyTorch model with `torch.save`. Now I want to load it as `GPT2LMHeadModel`. `from_pretrained` method looks for a directory, and then a HuggingFace registry, none of which exists. I simply have a serialized PyTorch model and an `nn.Module` class. How to I integrate them with the Transformers library? Training from scratch is not option (takes too long).

Comment: Can you please add the output of `torch.load('bla').keys()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Root cause

Your local path needs to be registered on the paths models' registry.

### Solution

I suggest you to use the [save_pretrained](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/main_classes/model#transformers.PreTrainedModel.save_pretrained) method. It registers the local directory for further use with .from_pretrained method.

```py
import torch
from transformers import GPT2LMHeadModel, GPT2Config

your_model = torch.load('path/to/your/model.pth')
state_dict = your_model.state_dict()
config = GPT2Config.from_pretrained('gpt2')
model = GPT2LMHeadModel(config)
model.load_state_dict(state_dict)

# Save local directory
model.save_pretrained('path/to/save/transformers_model')

# Now, you can load the Transformers model using from_pretrained
loaded_model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('path/to/save/transformers_model')
```

### Extra Ball:

Similar discussion on GitHub: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/7849